# Trino - Coordinator Worker Issue

Tags: trino

I got the below error in Coordinator Trino, Can anuone help to get rid of it?

> "2023-10-30T06:01:59.321Z        ERROR   http-worker-117
> io.trino.server.InternalAuthenticationManager   Internal
> authentication failed io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT
> signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity
> cannot be asserted and should not be trusted."

**config.properties - coordinator**

coordinator=true

node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false

http-server.http.port=8080

query.max-memory=5GB

query.max-memory-per-node=2GB

discovery-server.enabled=true

discovery.uri=http://0.0.0.0:8080

discovery-server.enabled=true

internal-communication.https.required=false

internal-communication.shared-secret=Testing@123

**config.properties - Worker**

coordinator=false

http-server.http.port=8080

query.max-memory=5GB

query.max-memory-per-node=1GB

discovery.uri=http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXX.com:8080

internal-communication.https.required=false

internal-communication.shared-secret=Testing@123 (edited)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somehow there is a difference between coordinator and worker for the value of the internal shared secret must be the same. Try changing them on both servers to a simple and identical value for starters.

Also disable all other authentication to be able to isolate the problem.